# jQuery and CSS colon selectors

Tags: jquery, css, dom, jquery-selectors

In jQuery, let's say we have 2 ways to navigate through the DOM elements;

1. Through the use of CSS colon selectors (e.g. `var x = $("#someElement:after")`)
2. Through the jQuery functions (e.g. `var x = $("#someElement").prev()`)

Now my questions are:

1. Is the return type same in both the cases?
2. What is the difference in navigating through the DOM in both the
   approaches?
3. Can we apply the same jQuery function to the result of both these
   statements? E.g. `x.css("someProp","someVal")`

Comment: I cannot find any information about `:after` in the documentation. Are you sure it exists? Afaik there are no pseudo selectors that let you traverse the DOM. But in any case, you always get a jQuery object if you pass a selector to jQuery.

Comment: Exists for sure: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

Comment: @atzu: Not in jQuery. We are talking about jQuery selectors, which is why I removed the [css-selectors] tag.

Comment: @atzu: Although it exists as CSS selector, it would not make sense to use it as jQuery selector (not sure if it even works).

Comment: @Felix Kling: See my comment on nickf's answer.

Comment: @BoltClock: Just saw it after I commented. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Just to add, can I get a complete list of jQuery CSS colon based selectors (mainly for DOM traversing)...I mean the one at their official page http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ does not specifically list the colon(:) selectors only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that ":after" exists but other than that:

1) The return type will be exactly the same for either (So long as its a valid selector)

2) The difference is fairly slight, its mostly about how you prefer do to things and in certain cases the ":first" may not be exactly what you want, in a loop for example. There are arguments about which has the best overhead but I don't know enough to comment.

3) Absolutely, as the return type is exactly the same (A jQuery element) you can use them in exactly the same way.

E.G:
$("#Test").parent();
would return exactly the same as
$("#Test:parent");

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/HenryGarle/2qcpK/

```
<div id="Parent1">
    <div id="Test1">Text</div>
</div>

<div id="Parent2">
    <div id="Test2">Text</div>
</div>


// replaces the content of Test1's parent
$("#Test1").parent().html("New Parent 1 content");

// replaces the content of Test2's parent
$("#Test2:parent").html("New Parent 2 content");
```

This would result in the DOM looking like:

```
<div id="Parent1">
    New Parent 1 content
</div>

<div id="Parent2">
    New Parent 2 content
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`:after` is a CSS pseudo-element which is not supported by jQuery. The documentation for jQuery's selectors is here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

I guess the equivalent of what you're looking for is the sibling selector: `+`:

```
// select whatever element comes after #someElement
var x = $("#someElement + *");
```

So, to answer your question generally, if you use the standard CSS selectors in a jQuery query, then it is possible that jQuery can hand off the searching to the browser if it is supported. If you use the jQuery functions, then these sort of shortcuts can't be done. My general rule of thumb is to use CSS selectors whenever possible, except when it hurts legibility.

The return result, regardless of the methods used to find your elements, is exactly the same.

Comment: There is no CSS equivalent for `.prev()` though :( Plus the reason why `:after` isn't supported in jQuery is because it's a **pseudo-element**, and pseudo-elements aren't part of the DOM.